# Set the color of a vue-swatches children component when rendering

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm currently working on a project using VueJS.

To be simple, I have a list of item, theses items contains a property named `color`.

When I click on one item of the list, properties of the item appears, and so the `color` property is showed in by a colorpicker ([Vue Swatches](https://saintplay.github.io/vue-swatches/)).

The thing is, I have a parent component where the colorpicker component is called, but this is not directly the `v-swatches` component which is called, it's a customized component.

### ColorPicker.vue (Customized Child Component)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-swatches v-model="color" v-on="listeners"></v-swatches>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VSwatches from "vue-swatches";
import "vue-swatches/dist/vue-swatches.css";

export default {
  name: "e-colorpicker",
  components: { VSwatches },
  data() {
    return {
      color: "#1CA085"
    };
  },
  computed: {
    listeners() {
      return {
        ...this.$listeners,
        input: this.updateColorValue
      };
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateColorValue(event) {
      this.$emit("input", event);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And I call this customized child component in a parent component:

### EditPlanning.vue (Parent Component)

```
// This is just a little part of my parent component code
<e-colorpicker
  class="position-relative"
  v-model="selectedItem.color"
  :value="selectedItem.color"
  :key="selectedItem.color"
/>
```

When I save changes in my parent page, I call a method which call an api (**POST updateItem()**) who update the specified item in my database and this part work perfectly fine.

**However**, when I refresh my page even if I fetch successfully from database the updated property color of the item, the customized colorpicker component is not getting and updating the `prop` **color** when rendering.

**Note**: The rendering of the colorpicker is only when I select an item from the item list I have in my parent component. So I have a `mounted` section in my parent component, which call the method `getItems()` which fetch the data from api.

So how can I update the color property of my child component `e-colopicker` just before it render?

EDIT:

Here is a picture of my problem:

#### Selecting color and save it

[image: Selected color]

#### After Reloading the page

[image: no selected color]

My wish would be to have the color getting updated when rendering the colorpicker with the previously saved selected color. The color is updated correctly in my database, is just the component which doesn't update the color when rendering on a refreshed page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass down the color from the parent component to the child component (`e-colorpicker`), you have to define a [prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) in the child component.

```js
props: ["color"],
```

Pass down the color from the parent to the child:

```html
<e-colorpicker
  class="position-relative"
  :color="selectedItem.color"
  :value="selectedItem.color"
  :key="selectedItem.color"
/>
```

Then bind the color to the `v-model`:

```html
<v-swatches v-model="color" v-on="listeners"></v-swatches>
```

And don't forget to **remove** the hard-coded color property:

```js
data() {
  return {
    color: "#1CA085"
  };
},
```

**Working [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-knuth-5jvx2).**

Comment: Hi I've actually did it, but the color is not properly set on my colorpicker when I render it. The color is successfully binded, so when I choose a color for my item, and save it, no problem, the color is updated, but when I reload the page, the colorpicker is set to white(since there's is no default color), where, I want it to display the previously saved color.

Comment: @SkydersZ, can you please check my updated answer? (see the working sandbox)

Comment: Hi, I've check the sandbox you've linked, but I've got `ModuleNotFoundError
Could not find module in path: './components/HelloWorld' relative to '/src/App.vue'` on the home page.

Does I need to edit the source code?

Comment: I forgot to save the files... please check again now: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-knuth-5jvx2

Comment: It's worked! Thanks! But now I have the following error in my console: `[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "color"`

Comment: It's probably because you're mutating the `color` prop directly inside `<e-colorpicker>` component.